# ImportError: cannot import name patterns

Tags: python, django

**Python Version:** 2.7.5

**Django Version:** 1.10

When I type `nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9001`
it shows me

[image]

I have googled and someone told me to `vi urls.py`, but it doesn't work. Another error occurred which shows that `cannot import name default`.

Comment: @e4c5 whether or not you like this question, the answer will be seen by hundreds/thousands of people when they google the `ImportError` message. We can either tidy up this question and leave a canonical answer, or ask a similar question and answer it.

Comment: fair point @Alasdair notice that you've taken some steps in that canonical answer direction. Also pls note that the close vote is not from me so I am not the only one who thinks this is a poor question.

Comment: Hello @Alex 
I got the same problem 10 minutes ago and I found out on Stackoverflow that the pattern module has been remove (it had been deprecated since 1.8)
I fixed the problem by replacing my current version of Django (1.10) by Django(1.8) using sudo pip install Djanog==1.8.
No worry it'll replace automatically the current version on your computer :)

Hope my post will be useful

Comment: @S7_0 Thank you very much ,Perfectly solved my problem.

Comment: i'm sorry about about that my non-standardized question caused trouble for everyone's reading.i'm newly here and my English is poor,I will pay more attention to this later. Tks @e4c5

Comment: @S7_0, It works fine but please fix the typo **"Djanog"**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use of patterns is deprecated since django 1.8. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/http/urls/). You can use plain lists now.

Comment: yes,i use pip install Django==1.8 and it works! thank you ,i'm not very clear  about the django,i'm just an OPS....

Answer (score 25):

The use of patterns is deprecated in Django1.10. Therefore do not import 'patterns' and your url pattern should be as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(........),
]
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this error when trying to install Django-Guardian. Instead of downgrading Django, you can install the latest version of Django-Guardian. 
Try,

```
pip install 'django-guardian>=1.4.6'
```

This resolved the issue for me.