# ImportError: cannot import name patterns in django application

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create a facebook extractor for my research. for the purpose I have tried many libraries, but could not find an example. lastly I have reached this [repository](https://github.com/omab/psa-allauth), which I guess is what I was looking for.

But the problem is when I ran the it, I cam e across the following error:

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000004540518>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo-pc\Desktop\psa-allauth-master\example\urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
ImportError: cannot import name patterns
```

I am quite puzzled by this error, as I am encountering it for the first time. Tell me what I can do to improve the code? I m using `Django 1.11.5` and `Python 2.7.2`.  Also there are no examples for `Django 1.11.5` related to social authentication, so can anyone help me with that. It will be a great help.
If I remove the `pattern` I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 85, in url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

Comment: The import error is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786036/importerror-cannot-import-name-patterns). Once you've removed the import, the `view must be a callable or a list/tuple` error is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744285/django-urls-error-view-must-be-a-callable-or-a-list-tuple-in-the-case-of-includ)

Answer (score 0):

The given project was last updated on 17 Mar 2015.

Seeing this, I am sure that the project was not build using Django1.11.5.

You should check by installing some older django version like Django1.8.

Comment: If I want to go with the current version then is there any solution?

Comment: If you were able to solve this issue under latest version, then you may stuck again somewhere else. I would suggest you to either go with Django 1.8 or write full project from scratch using Django 1.11

Answer (score 0):

From `1.8+` onwards **patterns is removed** and now In **current version** simply write like below, it will work fine.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'example.app.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout' kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
    . . . . . . 
    . . . . . .
]
```

> Update after comment:

You need to update django for that:

```
pip install django
```

Comment: @JafferWilson, I hope this makes sense to you. I too had faced the same issue earlier.

Comment: I guess you have not seen the last line of my question.. I tried it already. `File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 85, in url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().`

Comment: @JafferWilson, Try to get the newest version of django. That problem is coz of version.

Comment: I tried newer version.. as I have mentioned .. it is 1.11.5..... I will upgrade to 1.11.6 soon

Answer (score 0):

Try to install patterns

```
pip install patterns
```

then try your code.

Comment: I don't think the pattern in my code has anything to do with the `patterns` library. Still I will check.